# It is possible to edit the Android Studio SDK path inside a settings file?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, installation

I'm planning a full rollout of Android Studio + SDK in one of our rooms.
We have 20 clients on which I have installed Android Studio silent. When I first start Android Studio and go to the settings the path to the SDK directory is empty. The SDK is installed under **C:*User*\Appdata\Local\Android**. If I edit the path on every client it tooks to much time for me. I'm lazy :)

So anyone knows a solution how i can edit the path for example within a settings or .xml file?

Anyone out there who had the same problem or could understand me?